# How to make elastic search only match full field

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a query looking like this:

```
((company_id:1) AND (candidate_tags:"designer"))
```

However this also matches users where `candidate_tags` is `interaction designer`. **How do I exclude these?**

Here's my full search body:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query":
                        "((company_id:1) AND (candidate_tags:\"designer\"))"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    "sort":{
        "candidate_rating":{
            "order":"desc"
        },
        "candidate_tags",
        "_score"
    }
}
```

## Extra info

Realised now that an answer came in: `candidate_tags` is an array of strings, and say, a candidate has the tags `interaction designer` and `talent`, searching for `talent` should be a match but `designer` should not.

Comment: Make your `candidate_tags` field as `not_analyzed` or analyzed with `keyword` analyzer.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `candidate_tags` field as `not_analyzed` or analyzed with `keyword` analyzer.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "candidate_tags": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or add a `raw` field to your existent mapping like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "candidate_tags": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the first option use the same query as you use now.
For the second option use `candidate_tags.raw`, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "((company_id:1) AND (candidate_tags.raw:\"designer\"))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: I probably failed by not making clear `candidate_tags` is an array of strings, and I need an exact match per string.

Comment: You want to match those docs that have one tag only and that tag is the one from the query?

Comment: No, I want to match the docs of which at least one tag matches the query exactly. I updated my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use script:

```
POST test/t/1
{
"q":"a b"
}
POST test/t/2
{
  "q":"a c"
}
POST test/t/_search
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
    "filter": {
        "script": {
        "script": "return _source.q=='a b'"

     }
     }
  }
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. By filtering.
2. By making field candidate_tags an exact-value field - aka `not_analyzed` field ([Andrei Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498062/andrei-stefan)'s solution, answered above)

With #2 be careful that you don't later mix the field that is `not_analyzed` with those that are. More: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_exact_value_fields.html

With #1, your query would look something like that (written from memory, don't have ES on me so can't verify):

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query":
                        "((company_id:1) AND (candidate_tags:\"designer\"))"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "candidate_tags" : "designer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    "sort":{
        "candidate_rating":{
            "order":"desc"
        },
        "candidate_tags",
        "_score"
    }
}
```