# Elastic search retrieving results with half the value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to check whether client_id is already  exists in the index or not. but problem is ES still retrieving full ID, even though I am giving half of the id. here is the mapping.

```
'mappings': {
            'properties': {
                'client_id': {'index': 'true','type': 'keyword'},
                'client_name': {'index': 'true', 'type': 'keyword'},
                'data_index_server': {'type': 'ip'},
                'data_file_node_path': {'index': 'true', 'type': 'keyword'},
            }
```

If I  have the record like this

```
{
  "_index": "client_index",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "wYlkrYMB_q_jkYaCv6pU",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "doc": {
      "client_id": "0935be6b-61fe-4ec4-80c8-5c5ee8384378",
      "client_name": "citi",
      "data_file_node_path": " ",
      "data_index_server": " "
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "doc.client_id": [
      "0935be6b-61fe-4ec4-80c8-5c5ee8384378"
    ],
    "doc.client_name": [
      "sample_name"
    ],
    "doc.data_index_server": [
      " "
    ],
    "doc.client_name.keyword": [
      "citi"
    ],
    "doc.data_file_node_path.keyword": [
      " "
    ],
    "doc.client_id.keyword": [
      "0935be6b-61fe-4ec4-80c8-5c5ee8384378"
    ],
    "doc.data_index_server.keyword": [
      " "
    ],
    "doc.data_file_node_path": [
      " "
    ]
  }
}
```

my request for search is this. and if I am taking some part of the ID and search against it. I am expecting to be hits will be zero

```
POST /client_index/_search

    {
      "query": {
          "match": {
              "doc.client_id":"0935be6b-61fe-4ec4-80c8" ,
          }
      }
    }
```

I have follwed this url: [How to make elastic search only match full field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757901/how-to-make-elastic-search-only-match-full-field). change the fields type to keywords and also toggled index between true and false, but no result

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed up few things, in the mapping you showed just four properties which are simple fields, while in the search response, it has additional fields under `fields` which are of type `object`.

You read it correct, `keyword` fields are not analyzed and on these fields you will get results only on full field value.

You should just try to define your `client-id` as a keyword field in new index with your sample field and search on that index to see it in action.

Comment: That's not a response, it just full view of the record from KIBANA. I have already made client-id as keyword right?. can you please tell me more specific. this is first time i am working with ES

Comment: I just used  es.indices.create(index='client_index', body=request_body_client_index)". I am not sure why more fields are created

Comment: I have solved this by  adding doc.client_id.keyword in match braces

Comment: @Saivenkataraju i am not sure what you mean exactly, are you still facing issue?